# Equal Height Columns With Flexbox and Nested Divs

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, multiple-columns

I am currently trying to create a row of three equal height columns where all divs would be the same as the tallest div i.e. the div with the most text. I have tried adding flex: 1 and height: 100% but I can't seem to get these guys to be equal height. Here is the code I'm currently trying. You might have to expand the width to get them to line up in a row.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #565757;
}

.internal-icons-icon {
  margin: 20px 0;
   height: 100%;
}

.internal-icons-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
}



.internal-icons-icon > div {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #575859;
  color: #565757;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 10px 8px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}

.internal-icons-icon div {
  margin: 20px 0;

}

.internal-icons-content {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.internal-icons-title {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media (min-width: 990px) {
  .internal-icons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .internal-icons-layout {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .internal-icons-icon {
    margin: 0;
    width: 33.333%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
  }

  .internal-icons-content {
    flex: 1;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="internal-icons">
  <div class="internal-icons-layout">
    <div class="internal-icons-icon">
      <div>
        <div class="internal-icons-image">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/85/000000/money.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="internal-icons-title">
          Lorem Ipsum Dolor
        </div>
        <div class="internal-icons-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="internal-icons-icon">
      <div>
        <div class="internal-icons-image">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/85/000000/money.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="internal-icons-title">
          Lorem ipsum dolor
        </div>
        <div class="internal-icons-content">
          Fusce cursus, risus eu rhoncus varius, ipsum massa eleifend libero, non accumsan elit felis et augue.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="internal-icons-icon">
      <div>
        <div class="internal-icons-image">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/85/000000/money.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="internal-icons-title">
          Lorem ipsum dolor
        </div>
        <div class="internal-icons-content">
          Fusce cursus, risus eu rhoncus varius, ipsum massa eleifend libero, non accumsan elit felis et augue.
          <br />
          <strong>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR >></strong>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually I would use `CSS-Grid` instead. There you can use `grid-auto-rows: 1fr` which will size all rows to the height of the tallest row.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height: 100%` from `.internal-icons-layout` and put it on `.internal-icons-icon>div`.

The most nested container has to have the 100% height, and all parent containers will naturally expand to fit your 100% height container, so you only have to put 100% height on `.internal-icons-icon>div`. Now all your columns will expand to fit the flex container, which will be as tall as the tallest column.

Also added `flex-grow: 1` on `.internal-icons-icon` so that when your columns become rows, they will grow to fill the width.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #565757;
}

.internal-icons-icon {
  margin: 20px 0;
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.internal-icons-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.internal-icons-icon>div {
  height: 100%;
}

.internal-icons-icon>div {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #575859;
  color: #565757;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 10px 8px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}

.internal-icons-icon div {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.internal-icons-content {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.internal-icons-title {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media (min-width: 990px) {
  .internal-icons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .internal-icons-layout {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .internal-icons-icon {
    margin: 0;
    width: 33.333%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .internal-icons-content {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="internal-icons">
  <div class="internal-icons-layout">
    <div class="internal-icons-icon">
      <div>
        <div class="internal-icons-image">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/85/000000/money.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="internal-icons-title">
          Lorem Ipsum Dolor
        </div>
        <div class="internal-icons-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="internal-icons-icon">
      <div>
        <div class="internal-icons-image">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/85/000000/money.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="internal-icons-title">
          Lorem ipsum dolor
        </div>
        <div class="internal-icons-content">
          Fusce cursus, risus eu rhoncus varius, ipsum massa eleifend libero, non accumsan elit felis et augue.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="internal-icons-icon">
      <div>
        <div class="internal-icons-image">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/85/000000/money.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="internal-icons-title">
          Lorem ipsum dolor
        </div>
        <div class="internal-icons-content">
          Fusce cursus, risus eu rhoncus varius, ipsum massa eleifend libero, non accumsan elit felis et augue.
          <br />
          <strong>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR >></strong>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how will this resize the rows to the size of the heighest row? The rows are not related to each other in this markup.

Comment: @tacoshy Previous answer did work for `flex-direction: row`. You made me realise though that `align-items` was redundant and it was actually just a `height` issue.

Comment: @tacoshy Have also added flex-grow now for the issue when they become rows as you mention

Comment: @tacoshy does this answer still need to be downvoted